# Bash command not behaving as expected when invoked from Jenkins job

Tags: python, bash, jenkins

I have a python script which executes the following command:

```
commands.getstatusoutput("./some_program -bg; sleep 10; kill -SIGUSR2 `pidof 
                                some_program`; kill -9 `pidof some_program`")
```

In short, this calls a program (some_program) and puts it in the background, then, after 10s, it sends a signal to the program to prompt it to dump some data into a csv file, after which we kill the program.

When I run the python script manually, it dumps the output to the csv file as expected. When I run the program through a Jenkins build however, the csv file is not created.

Any ideas?

Comment: Sounds like a permission problem to me, are you running jenkins with a different user? I would `chmod 777` the folder temporally only to see if thatś the issue

Comment: Try running something very simple and robust, such as `/bin/cp /tmp/1 /tmp/2` (where `/tmp/1` exists and is world-readable) to see if things are executing at all.

Comment: Also, why not using **subprocess** to get the output of the script execution? you can do it like this `out = subprocess.check_output([YOUR_COMMANDS])`

Comment: Path problem perhaps with "./some_program"? Does it work with "DIRNAME/some_program" ?

Comment: It turns out it was an ownership issue.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a permission problem to me, are you running jenkins with a different user? I would `chmod 777` the folder temporally only to see if thatś the issue
                    – gerosalesc

It turns out it was an ownership issue. – user2548144